# IntoHandlerError not implemented for type that is listed as implemented for

Tags: rust

I have an error of type std::boxed::Box and I'd like to be able to use [`IntoHandlerError`](https://docs.rs/gotham/0.4.0/gotham/handler/trait.IntoHandlerError.html) to convert it to an error that [gotham](https://gotham.rs) can use. The compiler helpfully tells me:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `into_handler_error` found for type `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>` in the current scope
   --> web/src/main.rs:112:31
    |
112 |                     (state, x.into_handler_error())
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync>`
    |
    = note: the method `into_handler_error` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
            `&mut dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
            `&mut std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync> : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
            `&std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync> : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
            `dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
            `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync> : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
```

I'm sure I'm being a idiot but the type named at the top seems to exactly match the last type listed. What gives?

Adding a dereference doesn't seem to help:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `into_handler_error` found for type `&dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync` in the current scope
   --> web/src/main.rs:124:45
    |
124 |                 Err(e) => Err((state, (&*e).into_handler_error()))
    |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync`
    |
    = note: the method `into_handler_error` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&&dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
            `&dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
            `&mut &dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
            `&mut dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
            `dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync : gotham::handler::error::IntoHandlerError`
```

Comment: The list is bounds that are **not satisfied**. The message is just saying that `Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>` doesn't implement `IntoHandlerError`. Simple as that.

Comment: Of course. I really was being a dummy. And at some point I did know that's what the compiler was saying, but for some reason I got this flipped on it's head.

Comment: It's an understandable mistake. I think this error message used to be different, so you may be remembering the old format, which did not list all the ways the trait could be satisfied (I don't remember the exact details).

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that your object is a `Box<T>` and the impl is for a `&T`. Since `Box` implements `Deref`, rustc will search for a impl for the trait on `T` as well, but not on `&T`.

You can dereference the `Box` and borrow the contents as a `&` using `&*x` so try `(&*x).into_handler_error()`.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the suggestion, I've added an edit to show that I get basically the same error. It names my type, and gives that name again in the list of implementations, but claims the two aren't equal.